# Full Width (Block) Button Won't show with Styles in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, button, block

I'm not sure why, but it works across every other internet platform. 
First Pic is of button in IE, Second is code, third is button in Chrome.

[image: IE Button In live View][image: Code for Button]

[image: Chrome Button]
[image: HTML Button code][Link to webpage](http://partnership/OnlineLearning/SuccessfulBusinessWriting/Courses.cfm)

Comment: mentioned link not accessible, Please share your code

Comment: provide a snippet

Comment: @DCR  i updated it with snippet of code.

Answer (score 1):

I can't post a comment because of my low reputation so here we go.

Did you open this page in IE prior to adding this style? In my experience, IE has a very aggressive caching policy and will often not reload css files and such.

Comment: I did not...and what would you know..it worked. I hard refresh in chrome all the time. Not sure why I didn't think of this (i also never ever use EI), thanks!

Comment: From your last comment, it looks like this answer solved your issue. I suggest you can mark the helpful answer as an accepted answer to this question. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.